# Cant get Logitech G13 working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usb-device

I have a logitech g13 and would like to use it with my linux mint system but i dont know what to do. Im a noob that has some terminal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workable solution.

https://github.com/ecraven/g13

This is a "user space" tool that can be run at boot time or after login.

You need to be comfortable with running command line utilities, using git and GitHub, running a C++ compile, etc.

After following the install instructions you'll want a .bind file profile of the desired mappings, and a script to run it.  There are a few example .bind files in the project.

There's also a clock.sh script to display a ticking clock on the G13 display.

The start script I'm using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

base=`dirname $0`
cd "$base"

name=`basename $0 .sh`

echo "${name}, version 1.00"

if [ ! -w /dev/bus/usb ]; then
    echo "Must make usb writable."
    sudo -A chmod a+rw -R /dev/bus/usb/
fi

if [ ! -w /dev/uinput ]; then
    echo "Must make uinput writable."
    sudo -A chmod a+rw -R /dev/uinput
fi

${base}/g13d --config ${base}/g13-keys.bind --logo ${base}/logo.lpbm
```

This script can be used in a launcher from the desktop. The GitHub project includes graphic files can that can be used for launcher icons.

I use an all-Logitech setup with a G502 Hero mouse, G910 Orion Spectrum keyboard and a G13 gamepad/keypad. Have found a combination for all the lights and G-keys. All working on Linux Mint 20. Am happy to provide those details if anyone is interested. Not too far from Windows Logitech Gaming Software with a little fussing.